Configuring mTLS in nginx for postman client
I want to configure mTLS for my nginx reverse proxy, this is my nginx reverse proxy's default.conf configuration,
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name qa-app.example.com;
        
        ssl_certificate /home/bundle_chained.crt;
        
        #ssl_certificate /home/certificate.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/private.key;
        ssl_verify_client optional;
        ssl_client_certificate /home/bundle_chained.crt;

        #access_log off;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;


        # Disabling Insecure methods

        if ($request_method ~* ^(TRACK|TRACE|CONNECT)$) {
            return 405;
        }


        location /block1 {
                if ($ssl_client_verify != SUCCESS) {
                    return 403 '{"error": "Client certificate required"}';
                }

                rewrite ^/block1(.*)$ $1 break;
                proxy_pass http://block1-server:8587/;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }


        location /block2 {
                    rewrite ^/block2(.*)$ $1 break;
                    proxy_pass http://block2-server:8586/;
                    proxy_redirect off;
        }




        location / {
                    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
                    index  index.html index.htm;

                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name qa-app.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

This is the nginx.conf
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

I got my certificates from ZeroSSL, it's a wildcard certificate and the files I got are ca_bundle.crt and certificate.crt .
I generated the bundled certificate using this command
cat certificate.crt ca_bundle.crt > bundle_chained.crt
I also obtained the private.key as well.
As you can see in the above nginx configuration, I want the mTLS to be optional and for only that server block. So I have the IF condition in place for the appropriate location block.
For testing purposes, I used the Postman client.
For Which I added the bundle_chained certificate as shown in the image,


But when I make the appropriate API call I get 403 error and the JSON that I have hard coded in the IF block of nginx,
I followed these articles, but still couldn't get it to work.
https://medium.com/geekculture/mtls-with-nginx-and-nodejs-e3d0980ed950
https://smallstep.com/hello-mtls/doc/server/nginx
Any help would be appreciated.
